# Apache CXF Send custom response, abort interceptor chain

Tags: java, spring, cxf

I have three interceptors and their execution order is as follows:
- Security Interceptor
- Authentication Interceptor
- Authorization Interceptor

First Security interceptor runs and if it fulfills security requirements then Authentication interceptor invokes and if authentication is done then AuthorizationInterceptor should invoke and  authorize the call.

But problem is that I need to abort the next two ( authentication , authorization ) interceptors if security is not fulfilled and return custom response from SecurityInterceptor.

If I call message.getInterceptorChain().abort(); then no response is sent. 
How do I abort processing of interceptors and send custom response ?

My Security interceptor is at Phase.Receive and other two interceptors are at Phase.PRE_INVOKE phase.

Answer (score 1):

You should throw **Fault** not call interceptror.abort()

Comment: Karthik How can I send custom response through fault chain from an Interceptor in CXF ?

Comment: If you have say defined @WebFault for class FaultResponse with custom message structure, then you can throw FaultReponse